# How to enable SharedArrayBuffer between LWC and embedded Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, iframe, video

I have an LWC with a Visualforce page embedded in an iframe.  The Visualforce page is using the Zoom Meeting SDK for Web to embed a Zoom client in the page.  I couldn't use the SDK directly in the LWC because it directly manipulates the DOM.  I am having a problem with frozen video which I think may be caused because the Visualforce page can't use the SharedArrayBuffer because the LWC and the Visualforce page are served from different origins (*.lightning.force.com vs. *.vf.force.com).  In order to cross-origin isolate the whole thing, I need to set the COOP/COEP https headers, but I don't know if that is even possible.  There are checkboxes in the Session Settings to enable them for Visualforce pages, but how could I set them for the parent page?  Also, it doesn't specify what values they are set to for Visualforce pages.  This is a huge blocker for my client's project, as embedded video call functionality is a must-have. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your VF Page acts as a renderer ? Then it wouldnt allow you to do any scripting on it and CORS issue will persists. You can try that in Aura as it would render your VF Page